# Hidden field value gets lost at request object

Tags: forms, hidden

I have a strange situation with following code.

```
<input type="hidden" id="Report_Person_ID" value="<%= user.PersonID.ToString() %>" />
<input type="hidden" id="Report_Organization_ID" value="<%= user.OrganizationID.ToString() %>" />
<input type="hidden" id="Report_Company_ID" value="1" />
```

I am setting values as previous code displays and expect to receive on target page. I can have first two hidden fields values using Request object but the third one gives me value of "0" which I provide "1" in the page that sends these values. Following is the code in the page I try to get these values:

```
reportCompanyID = Request["Report_Company_ID"]; //gives me "0"
reportPersonID = Request["Report_Person_ID"];
reportOrganizationID = Request["Report_Organization_ID"];
```

More interesting to me is if I change the name "Report_Company_ID" to, say, "Comp_ID" in source and target it even doesn't give me "0" but "" instead. I feel I do miss something very easy to solve this, but I got stuck at this point.

Comment: your `<input>` tag must be wrapped inside a `<form>` and must have a `name` attribute.

Comment: yes it has a form tag

Comment: how about `name` attribute? `<input type="hidden" id="Report_Person_ID" name="Report_Person_ID" value="..." />` ???

Comment: You are right, it solved my problem thank you. Isn't it weird the 2 have correct values but the last one don't? I am a little confused.